# Itô Excursion Measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am looking for any source of information regarding Itô Excursion Measure (for Brownian Motion). I am looking for a selfcointained reference (Though I have basic knowledge on Local Times and Poisson Point Processes). In particular I am looking forward to studying random trees derived from excursion processes and I was trying to cover as thoroughly as posible the prequisites.

I have found some references (particularly the Revuz Yor book) but it takes too long to get to what I want and notation is really strange for me (in particular the way he defines point poisson processes).

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: Have you tried Kallenberg's book "Foundations of modern probability"?